# Javascript Scoping Issue or Instantiation Issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, scope

I have a webpage that does some calculations on the fly based on user 'keyup' events in a text input field. It's a rather large page that is built dynamically, so I have to keep a Hash/Array of values that I can reference from other locations within the page.

So at the top of the page I am doing this -

```
var itemBalanceHash = new Array();
var itemID_2_POIDHash = new Array();
var currentPODocumentID;
var warningArray = new Array();
```

Then I go on to define a number of functions that use these variables I just defined.
However, it is not until after I finish defining these functions that these variables start getting used (i.e. filled with stuff.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                
itemBalanceHash["${topitem.itemIdentifier}"]="${topitem.itemOutstandingEncumberedAmount}";
itemID_2_POIDHash["${topitem.itemIdentifier}"] = currentPODocumentID;
</script>
```

This script block appears in the middle of my page as it is getting built.  In fact, it gets called multiple times depending on how many rows I need to fill (a result set of a query from the database).

Anyhow - This works great in Firefox.  However, it does not work in IE8, Chrome or Safari.
I haven't tested this in older versions of IE; but I assume it will not work there either.

The error message Internet Explorer Debugger is giving me is this

"itemBalanceHash is undefined"

So, my question: 
Is this a scoping issue?
Firefox seems to have corrected my error somewhere, but where?

I can provide more code if necessary.  Thanks for your help!
It is most appreciated!

Comment: Is the top script only those four lines? How is it included?

Comment: You could use [`{}` (shorthand for `new Object()`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) instead of [`new Array()` (has a shorthand `[]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Array_literals), since you don't actually need an array.

Comment: You really should use objects (`{}`) for the hashes, javascript Arrays are for number-indexed arrays [only].

Comment: Yeah - I changed it to the shorthand version.  It didn't do anything. thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Esailija - I just include it directly in the same JSP page (not as a link).

Comment: Are all of these items declared in global scope (i.e. not inside of functions) and appear int hat order in the page source?

Comment: Fire up your debugger, set break point on initialization and use of hash table. You'll get your answer faster, and if you don't it may be easier for us to guess.

Comment: So, the debugger stops on the section of code where I use the hash table first! In fact, when I try to add a breakpoint next to the intialization - the IE8 debugger will not let me saying that "This section of code has not been loaded yet."  The section of code where these rows are being built I should mention occur within an iframe!  DOH!  That must be the problem.  The hash tables apply to a completely differently scope!!!! Wow - Firefox is smart!  It figured out that I'm a dope and fixed that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was with iframes!
Firefox executes all the JS code in my JSP page for me.
IE, Chrome and Safari needed to have Event Listeners attached to the page that would trigger the load event that would then execute my JS code (where the instantiation for this object was supposed to happen).

Very interesting.  I expected something like this from Microsoft, but I'm surprised Google and Safari behave in a similar fashion.  Just another reason why FF is my default browser.

Thanks for everyone's help/responses.

Cheers!